# A table in a figure - use caption or figcaption?

Tags: html, html-table

With the advent of HTML5, I'm starting to use `figure` to enclose images and tables, among other things. Up until now I've used the table's `caption` element to label the table. However, `figcaption` can be used to label the figure's content. It seems that in the case of a table within a figure, there are two elements that serve more or less the same purpose.

On one hand, `caption` is specific to describing the table's purpose; on the other hand `figcaption` is a little broader, yet would apply to the table as well as other figure content.

Would it be appropriate to use `figcaption` to label tables in figures, if for nothing else than consistency with other figures containing different elements?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element):

> When a table element is the only content in a figure element other than the figcaption, the caption element should be omitted in favor of the figcaption.

And while they currently match, here's a corresponding link to the [W3C Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-caption-element), just in case.

Comment: This seems to have a curious consequence when dealing with HTML within EPUBs. Some ereader software/hardware seems to have some kind of 'view table' functionality that opens just a table, I assume for potentially better viewing. But when following this recommendation this results in the caption being detached from the table in the readers I have tested it with (Kindle and Calibre, though not Adobe Digital Editions which doesn't seem to have this 'view table' functionality).